# How can i turn a website overlay design scale statically according to the screen size (not responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I designed a website without even thinking about it being responsive and put every element to position pixel by pixel with CSS like this

```
.contentFooterObese{
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(154, 158, 160);
  font-size: 150%; 
  left: 850px;
  top: -190px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.contentFooterPoverty{
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(154, 158, 160);
  font-size: 150%; 
  left: 700px;
  top: -180px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

so as you can see all my elements are positioned with absolute and responsive positions with using top n px and left n px. I know that it's too late to turn this into a responsive site. So how can I make the site size statically and not move any elements? here's the site now 
https://yusufkerem.github.io/ben-webtech-project/

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of things that make the size adjustable…
but I will try to introduce the simplest thing.
on your CSS… most of the unit size is static ( in pixels )
for example

```
 width: 400px
```

changing the measurement unit to a percentage could make the result more adaptable to the window size.

for example

```
 width: 80%
```

hope this simple thing helps.